# Passing some value from one page to other page in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to call other page from my current one , Write now I am using props.history.push(destination_page) but with that I want to pass some values also to that destination page so that there I can set the default filter. Is state mangement methods are the only way to pass the value ?

Comment: you can pass value using url

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Answer (score 1):

Route [state](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)

```
props.history.push({
  pathname: destination_page,
  state: {
    payload_to_send,
  },
});
```

Access via the [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) prop on the receiving route

```
props.location.state.payload_to_send
```

*You can also send data as plain text in the URL query parameters, retrieved via `props.location.search`, but string represents the entire query so you'll need a bit of extra logic/processing to extract the key-value pairs.*